# Gradle + Tomcat plugin + slf4j

Tags: java, tomcat, gradle

I'm using `apply plugin: 'com.bmuschko.tomcat'` for tomcat deployments, we usually use maven but this time we change to gradle, after several tries using intellijidea as my IDE, I'm not able to run the `tomcatRun` task, there is a weird error saying.

```
Failed to instantiate SLF4J LoggerFactory
Reported exception:
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/slf4j/spi/LoggerFactoryBinder
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
....
....
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: org.slf4j.LoggerFactory could not be successfully initialized.
at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getILoggerFactory(LoggerFactory.java:354)
at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:294)
```

I already have this config in the gradle.build

```
   log4jVersion = '1.2.17'
   slf4jVersion = '1.7.12'
   compile "log4j:log4j:$log4jVersion"
   compile "org.slf4j:slf4j-log4j12:$slf4jVersion"
```

I'm using also just gradle and run `gradle tomcatRun` and the same happens, the gradle version I tried is 2.6 and 2.10 with the same results.

Seems the war file is being created correctly with the libs on it, but using the plugin and gradle makes strange combination, any highlight here ?
Also other question is if there is another plugin for gradle-tomcat elsewhere?

Forgot to add, I'm using  `tomcatVersion = '6.0.44'` and java7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem and resolved it using gradle wrapper, with gradle verison 2.3. see https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/gradle_wrapper.html

add gradle wrapper

```
gradle wrapper --gradle-version 2.3
```

then run tomcat with

```
gradlew tomcatRun
```

Comment: Actually is how I resolved in the past, need to downgrade the version of the gradle to 2.3 which is the one that is used but STS, I figure it out as some of my teammates did not have the trouble on their computers, moving to older gradle version is a workaround, but I consider you answer as correct, thanks.